# GORM with Spring Boot and PostgreSql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, grails-orm

Does anyone have used GORM with Spring Boot and PostgreSql. If yes kindly share the dependancies.
I am trying with the below dependencies but facing error.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
// <1>
compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate5-spring-boot:6.1.6.RELEASE")
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.0.Final"

// <2>
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.0"
runtime "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:8.5.0"
runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10"

runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
```

}

Let me know if more information needed.